# Domain API Loop

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, dns

How can I perform the following with this API?

Form is setup in PHP for registered user to enter domain name
On submit..

**Check** if domain is available >

- If NO > output to XML > run the loop again in 5 minutes
- If YES > output to XML > go ahead and **purchase** (register) the domain > end loop

Thank you!

**Sample API code**

```
<?php /**  * Set the API URL  */ $sApiUrl = "https://www.apiurl.com/";


/**  * Set POST Parameters  */ $aParams = Array(
            'uid'     => "--USERNAME--",    // Username
            'pw'      => "--APIKEY--",      // API Key
            'command' => "querydomain",     // Command to Rum
            'sld'     => "sampledomain",    // Main part of the Domain
            'tld'     => "com");         // Domain Extension


/**  * Run the cURL command  */
$oCurl = curl_init(); curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $sApiUrl);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $aParams);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$sResponse = curl_exec($oCurl); curl_close($oCurl);


/**  * Turn results into Simple XML Object  */
$oOutput = new SimpleXmlElement($sResponse);


/**  * Debugging output, so we can see what we just got  */
print_r($oOutput);

?>
```

**API Commands**

```
check Checks whether a domain name is available for registration.
purchase Registers a new domain name.
transfer Requests a domain transfer to registrar.
extend Extends (renews) domain registration.
changepassword Changes the domain password.
sendpassword Send domain password to domain owner.
contacts Changes domains contacts.
querydomain Returns detailed information about the domain.
sendepp Sends gTLD epp key to domain owner.
refillaccount Refills your reseller account with funds.
changedomainns Changes domains name servers.
sendtransferemail Sends transfer authorisation request to domain owner.
addchildns Add child name server to domain.
updatechildns Update details for child name server.
removechildns Remove child name server from domain.
pushdomain Push domain to another registrar reseller.
getdnsrecords Get domain name server records for a domain.
enablednsdomain Create DNS domain service for domain.
adddnsrecord Add new DNS record to domain.
updatednsrecord Update DNS record for a domain.
removednsrecord Remove DNS record from a domain.
updatednssoa Update DNS SOA record for a domain.
disablednsdomain Destroy DNS domain service for a domain.
getmailrecords Get mail forwarding records for a domain.
addmailforwarder Add a mail forwarder to a domain.
removemailforwarder Remove a mail forwarder from a domain.
updatemailforwarder Update the details of a Mail Forwarder for a domain.
geturlrecords Get URL Forwarding records for a domain.
addurlforwarder Add a URL Forwarding record to a domain.
updateurlforwarder Update a URL Forwarding record for a domain.
removeurlforwarder Remove a URL Forwarding record for a domain.
getreglock Get registry lock details for a domain.
setreglock Set a registry lock for a domain.
updatecontact Update an address book entry.
getapiinfo Get information about the Domain System API.
transferout Push a domain name to another registrar, given their tag.
```

**Outputted XML from example above**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
```

(
    [results] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

```
[errors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [error] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [domain] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [name] => google.com
                        [status] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [code] => 211
                                [text] => Unavailable
                                [description] => The domain name you queried has been registered through another registrar.
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[errorcount] => 1
[exectime] => 0.399 second(s)
[enviroment] => live
[version] => 2.3.9 beta
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I can see what it is you are trying to do.  However which part in particular are you having issues with?   It looks as though you have the API already.  Is it not functioning correctly?

Do you need help in writing the PHP to do your 'Yes'/'No' step above?

And why are you "checking again in 5 minutes"?

Comment: I have no idea how to achieve the loop utilising the API and PHP. I will update the OP with the outputted XML from the example above. I just need some help coding the php script to do the check, using the api and xml output. Possible even to run the loop after a sleep of 30 seconds? Thank you so much!

Comment: Forgot to answer your query..
The reason for the check is to check if available (it's about to be purged from the registry), register, if unavailable (not purged yet), try again and again until it is available.